Why custom API https://reqres.in/api/login is not called and http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/credentials calls instead in next auth
I am working on Next-auth and the problem I am facing is, I am giving custom API route in authorize function in option.ts file. But I think it is not calling that API,
Here is the options.ts file in which there is authorize function and the login api is called inside it
options.ts
`
import { baseurl } from "@/api/apiConfig";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import { NextApiRequest } from "next";

interface User {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  // Add any other fields that you expect in the user object
}

export const options: NextAuthOptions = {
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },

  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/login",
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: "email:",
          type: "text",
          placeholder: "your-cool-username",
        },
        password: {
          label: "Password:",
          type: "password",
          placeholder: "your-awesome-password",
        },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        if (!credentials?.email || !credentials?.password) return null;
        const { email, password } = credentials;
        console.log(
          credentials,
          "....................credentials in options.ts"
        );
        const res = await fetch("https://reqres.in/api/login", {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify({
            email,
            password,
          }),
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        });

        const user: User | { message: string } = await res.json();

        if (res.status === 200 && "id" in user) {
          return user;
        } else {
          console.log(user, "/.,,,,check error");
          throw new Error(
            JSON.stringify({
              errors: (user as { message: string }).message,
              status: false,
            })
          );
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
};


And route.ts is
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import { options } from "./options";
options;
const handler = NextAuth(options);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };


**
middleware.ts**
In middleware, mostly we do protected routes
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function middleware(req: any) {
  const session = await getToken({ req, secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET });
  const { pathname } = req.nextUrl;

  const publicPaths = [
    "/login",
    "/register",
    "/api/auth",
    "/_next/static",
    "/_next/image",
  ];

  const isPublicPath = publicPaths.some((path) => pathname.startsWith(path));

  if (!isPublicPath && !session) {
    const loginUrl = new URL("/login", req.url);
    loginUrl.searchParams.set("callbackUrl", req.url);
    return NextResponse.redirect(loginUrl);
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}

export const config = {
  // https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware#matcher
  matcher: ["/", "/terms", "/contact", "/dashboard", "/profile"],
};


signin form
Here is the signin form where we call signIn function which I think executes the code in credentialProviders
Loign.tsx
"use client";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import Input from "../shared/Input";
import { Form, SubmitHandler, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { signIn, useSession, signOut, getSession } from "next-auth/react";
import AuthLayout from "./AuthLayout";
import Button from "../shared/Button";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { loginSchema } from "@/schema/authSchema";
import { baseurl } from "@/api/apiConfig";

interface FormState {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  error: any;
  errMsg: string;
  name: string;
}
function Login() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<FormState>({
    resolver: zodResolver(loginSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      name: "",
      error: "",
    },
  });
  const { data: session, status, ...rest } = useSession();
  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormState> = async (data) => {
    console.log("I am called");
    console.log(data);

    try {
      const response: any = await signIn("credentials", {
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password,
        redirect: false,
      });
      console.log({ response });
      if (!response?.error) {
        router.push("/");
        router.refresh();
      }

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
      }
      // Process response here
      console.log("Login Successful", response);
      // toast({ title: "Login Successful" });
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.error("Login Failed:", error);
      // toast({ title: "Login Failed", description: error.message });
    }
  };
  return (
    <AuthLayout>
      <div>
        <span className="text-h1 font-h1 text-white flex justify-center">
          Login
        </span>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <Input
            label={"Email"}
            name="email"
            type={"email"}
            placeholder={"xyz@gmail.com"}
            register={register}
            error={errors.email?.message}
          />
          <Input
            label={"Password"}
            name="password"
            type={"password"}
            placeholder={"aBc@123*"}
            register={register}
            error={errors.password?.message}
          />
          <Button
            label={"Login"}
            height={"h-16"}
            width={"w-full"}
            bg={"bg-formBtnBg"}
            color={"text-white"}
            type={"submit"}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    </AuthLayout>
  );
}

export default Login;
[![enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/2dPt4LM6.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/2dPt4LM6.png)

